# I need to point to Intel graphics card drivers on Ubuntu 18.04 LTS. How can I do that?

Tags: drivers, 18.04, graphics, intel-graphics

I am using this software [VAPOR3](https://www.vapor.ucar.edu/docs/installation)  and the developers of that software want me to use Intel Graphics card drivers  rather than Mesa. How can I do that ? When I type

```
 glxinfo | grep -i opengl
```

I get these messages

```
OpenGL vendor string: Intel Open Source Technology Center
OpenGL renderer string: Mesa DRI Intel(R) HD Graphics 630 (Kaby Lake GT2)
OpenGL core profile version string: 4.5 (Core Profile) Mesa 18.0.5
OpenGL core profile shading language version string: 4.50
OpenGL core profile context flags: (none)
OpenGL core profile profile mask: core profile
OpenGL core profile extensions:
OpenGL version string: 3.0 Mesa 18.0.5
OpenGL shading language version string: 1.30
OpenGL context flags: (none)
OpenGL extensions:
OpenGL ES profile version string: OpenGL ES 3.2 Mesa 18.0.5
OpenGL ES profile shading language version string: OpenGL ES GLSL ES 3.20
OpenGL ES profile extensions:
```

Answer (score 0):

Just go to your **system settings>defaults** there you can change the current graphics card being used by your system.
Hope this helps you.
Thank you..

Comment: I can see "Settings" now but defaults does not show current graphics card. So some screen shot will help

Comment: system settings>additional driver..there you can see both intel and nvidia (or) amd whichever is in your system..then you can choose one..

Comment: I am using linux distro so unable to provide you with the screenshots.

Comment: I do not see additional driver on my Ubuntu 18.04

Comment: can uh show the output of 'lspci -k | grep -A 2 -i "VGA"'

Comment: From your above output you are using Intel graphics card so no need to do anything.